# Strange behavior when getting element height inline - it takes time to get the right heigh

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a slider with 100 images and I want to extract the `height` of each of its parents (the wrapper) so I use an inline `onload` event:

```
<div class="wrap" style="height: 100%">
  <img src="<%=i.src%>" style="width: 100%; max-height: 100%" onload="
       var maxHeight = $(this).parent().height();
       console.log(maxHeight)">
 </div>
```

I can get correct readings on the image `height`. The problem is with the parent `.wrap` element.
The strange thing is that only about half of the images log the right `height` (almost the first half of them log `0 height` and only the other half log the correct `height`) and if I wrap the javascript inside a `setTimeout` function then I can see that the more time I use the more I get logs with the correct `height` until a time where all logs are correct. So I know that this has to do with the timing of the `load` event, but by the time it fires shouldn't everything be rendered because I'm trying to get father's `height`?
So:
1) Why is this happening?
2) How to make it work?

Comment: this is probably because image is loaded but dom is not updated yet... can't you just use image height? that should be valid in onload function

Comment: Keep in mind that `height()` returns only the height of the content area. It excludes the padding, border and margin of the element. If you need that included, use `.outerHeight()`

Comment: You're both right and for images I have no problem as I always get the correct values. This is a more DOM general issue, like you said, but what I don't get is that the father element should be rendered...So, this is related with how the DOM renders in this particular situation.